# How do I pick one by one file in a folder to rename the extension using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have some files in a folder. I want to rename the extension one by one. After I change the first extension file, I will do some process, then I come back again to change the next extension and do the process again.

I still can not figure out to rename it one by one, I only can rename all the files at the same time.

```
Function PICK_JOB
{
Write-Host "Pick 1st Job"
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\F1 -File |
    ForEach-Object { Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination "C:\Users\F1\$($_.BaseName).TXT" }
} 

Function BEGIN
{
Write-Host "Creating"
& .\Folder.ps1 #execute a powershell script
Write-Host ">>>>>>Creating Finished<<<<<<"
}

#------------------------#
Function END
{
#Do some process
}
Function END_Proc
{
#Do some process
}
Function CHK
{
  if($MLG -eq "1" -and $b_UB -eq "101")
{ 
    Write-Host ">>>>>>BEGIN<<<<<"
    BEGIN
    PICK_JOB
}

if($MLG -eq "1" -and $b_UB -eq "444")
{ 
    END
    PICK_JOB
}

else
{
    END_Proc
}
}

$MLG = "1"
$b_UB = "101"
$b = CHK
$A = BEGIN
```

Comment: as an aside - please try to avoid using words that are PoSh keywords in your code. the words `begin`, `process`, and `end` are used in advanced functions to denote the `run once at the beginning`, `run once for each pipeline item`, and `run once after all items are finished`. you really otta NOT use those words except where they are intended to be used OR when you must - and can take steps to ensure you are not causing problems by using those words.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe i see something wrong but...

right now you are

```
changing extansion{}
Process{}
```

but you need to

```
Changing extansion{
  Process{}
}
```

i hope this isn't wrong and you can get to your solution

Comment: You are right the skript is calling `BEGIN` and then iterate in `PICK_JOB`. He needs two different `PICK_JOB` and each one needs to call `END` or `BEGIN` in the ForEach-loop

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify what you are doing:

This is your code:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\F1 -File |
    ForEach-Object { Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination "C:\Users\F1\$($_.BaseName).TXT" }
}
```

`Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\F1 -File` gets every `-File` in the `-Path C:\Users\F1`.
`| ForEach-Object {}` will do something with **every single item** that the former line returned.
`Copy-Item ... -Destination "C:\...\$($_.BaseName).TXT"` will copy the item `$_` (which is the current item that is beeing proccessed) and rename it `$($_.BaseName).TXT`. That is (obviously) the `BaseName` + `.TXT`.

So yes you are renameing all of them in one step. If you want to process the items, you have to do it inside the `ForEach-Object {}`-block. If you want to rename them individually you have to filter them somehow with `if` statements inside the `ForEach-Object {}`-block or before you pipe (`|`) them into the  `ForEach-Object {}`-block.

Answer (score 0):

Will this work for you? All i did was rearrange ur existing `function` to a more comprehensible format.

```
Function PICK_JOB
{
    Write-Host "Pick 1st Job"
    Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\F1 -File |
    ForEach-Object {
        Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination "C:\Users\F1\$($_.BaseName).TXT"
        <#call your process here#> 
    }
}
```

This will call ur other process after every file operation

Comment: It change all the files one time in the folder. My expectation, I can change the extension file one by one.

Answer (score 0):

Call your process function in given block to solve your problem

```
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\F1 -File |
    ForEach-Object { 
          Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination "C:\Users\F1\$($_.BaseName).TXT" 
          # CALL YOUR PROCESS FUNCTION HERE
}
```